# Jenkins on Kubernetes not spawning slaves

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline

I am completely new to Kubernetes and having a lot of issues setting up Jenkins. Most of the issues I have gone through and solved though this one is killing me. For some reason, my Jenkins instance is not spawning new instances to run the jobs.

I have installed Jenkins using Helm (https://hub.helm.sh/charts/stable/jenkins). Below is my values configuration file:

```yaml
master:
  installPlugins:
    - kubernetes:1.12.6
    - workflow-job:2.24
    - workflow-aggregator:2.5
    - credentials-binding:1.16
    - git:3.9.1
  runAsUser: 0
  fsGroup: 0
  cpu: "2"
  numExecutors: 0
  memory: "3500Mi"
  javaOpts: "-Xms3500m -Xmx3500m"
  serviceType: NodePort
  hostName: *my-domain*
  ingress:
    enabled: true
    hostName: *my-domain*
    annotations:
      kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
      cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
    tls:
      - secretName: jenkins-tls-secret
agent:
  enabled: true
  image: "jenkins/jnlp-slave"
  tag: "3.27-1"
  workingDir: "/home/jenkins"
  componentName: "jenkins-slave"
  resources:
    requests:
      cpu: "512m"
      memory: "512Mi"
    limits:
      cpu: "512m"
      memory: "512Mi"
```

I have setup the kubernetes plugin and a new cloud node 'Kubernetes' with not changes to any of the values (as per a suggestion i found online). When I test connection, everything works perfectly.

Inside the logs for Jenkins, i only see 1 weird thing:

```
2020-07-13 15:32:45.746+0000 [id=94]    INFO    o.c.j.p.k.KubernetesClientProvider$SaveableListenerImpl#onChange: Invalidating Kubernetes client: kubernetes null
```

I have no idea on how to further debug the issue due to my lack of experience in Kubernetes. I have searched all across google but cant find anything that fixes this issue. Hopefully someone can help!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the cause of the issue was due to the kubernetes configuration not having the correct tunnel and URL

Comment: Could you please explain your answer in more detail?